# Fill a dynamically created DataGridView on a dynamically created form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2015

I have an MDI form with a Menu that creates a MenuItem for each of the Tables in the DataSet when the Form Loads. The intention is that the user to selects a MenuItem and the corresponding form opens, adding some layout items and a DataGridView that displays the Data from the underlying table.

I have managed to create the DataGridView on the dynamically created form and have managed to set its DataBinding to the Table selected by the user in the MenuItem. (i.e I can see the correct column titles at the top of the grid)

I wish to know how to Fill the DataGridView with the data in my database. I figured it has something to do with TableAdapters but they are proving to be mysterious.

Here is my code:

```
    private void formLoad(String formName,string formTag)
    {
        //Create a new form
        Form frm = new Form();
        frm.Text = "Manage " + formName + " (" + formTag + ")";
        frm.Size = new Size(900, 600);

        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Show();

        //Add Table to form
        TableLayoutPanel tlpAdd = new TableLayoutPanel()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            RowCount = 2,
            ColumnCount = 2,
            CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single

        };

        frm.Controls.Add(tlpAdd);
        //Data Grid

        DataGrid grdAdd = new DataGrid();
        DataSet ds = this.myDataSet1;

        grdAdd.SetDataBinding(ds, formTag);

        grdAdd.Name = formTag;
        grdAdd.AutoSize = true;
        grdAdd.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        tlpAdd.SetRow(grdAdd, 1);
        tlpAdd.SetColumn(grdAdd, 2);
        tlpAdd.SetRowSpan(grdAdd, 2);
        tlpAdd.Controls.Add(grdAdd);

        //Add FlowLayoutPannel for buttons
        FlowLayoutPanel flwAdd = new FlowLayoutPanel()
        {
            //AutoSize = true,
            Size = new Size(600, 25),
            Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight


        };
        tlpAdd.Controls.Add(flwAdd);
        tlpAdd.SetColumnSpan(flwAdd, 2);
        tlpAdd.SetColumn(flwAdd, 1);
        tlpAdd.SetRow(flwAdd, 2);

        //Add Data management Buttons etc to flow layout




    }
```

Comment: grdAdd.DataSource = myDataSet1[0]; thats all you need ;)

Comment: Sebi is correct.  You have a lot of unnecessary code to create DGV that can be removed.

Comment: Table adapters are only used to fill the dataset.  If you already have data in the dataset then the adapters aren't needed.  Do you have data in the dataset?

Comment: That does not work I get an error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataSet'